# CSS pointer-events and tooltip

Tags: jquery, css, events, pointers, tooltip

I have this setup: http://jsfiddle.net/V3fUa/11/

When mouse gets over green tooltip in ie10 or below, mouse movestops. Is there a way to prevent this, maybe append svg to tooltip or something?

Markup :

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b">tooltip</div>
```

Script :

```js
$('.a').bind('mousemove', function(e){
    $('.b').css({
        left:e.pageX,
        top:e.pageY
    })
})
```

CSS :

```css
.a{
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;

}
.b{
    position:absolute;
    background:green;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```